# Split Content on CKEDITOR and get HTML of each part

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, ckeditor

I have a CKEDITOR and i am trying to split the content in n parts, the user indicates how many parts he wants, by puting the cursor on a specific position of the CKEDITOR, after that with an option at the context-menu the user selects "Split Block", this inserts a

---

tag in HTML:

the user can do this n times in CKEDITOR, it is to indicate how many blocks the user wants to split the content, each hr inserted is one block.

So when the user finish, click at the context-menu "Process Split", this action should execute and split the content in n parts.

this is my code to split the content:

```
var index = 0;
var tmpItem = null;
var ranges = new Array();

var elements = editor.document.getElementsByTag( 'hr' );

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.count() ; i++ )
{

    var item = elements.getItem( i );

    ranges[index] = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );

    if(tmpItem!=null)
        ranges[index].setStart(tmpItem, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START);

    else{
        ranges[index].setStartAfter(editor.document.getBody().getFirst());

    }


    if(item.hasClass('split-end')){

        ranges[index].setEnd(item, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START);
        ranges[index].select();

        index++;

        var sel = editor.getSelection();
        var ran = sel.getRanges();
        var el = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div");

        for (var j = 1, len = ran.length; j < len-1; ++j) {
            el.append(ran[j].cloneContents());
        }

        console.log( el.getHtml() );

    }

    tmpItem = item;

}
```

The problem is: how to select from begining of the document to the first HR and so on.

Thanks a lot, i have been trying to do this for over a week, and i dont know what else try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not analyzing your code carefully, because I don't even know what you're trying to achieve. But here're some notes that can help you.

1. You use `CKEDITOR.dom.range#setStart` and `#setEnd` improperly. You should utilize `setStartAt` and `setEndAt`. Methods you used take offset as a second argument, not a position.
2. To select content from the beginning of the document to the first HR (including it):

   ```
   var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( document );
   range.setStart( document.getBody(), 0 );
   range.setEndAt( hr, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_END );
   range.select();
   ```
3. In your code I see that you're trying to select many ranges - it won't work this way. AFAIK only Firefox handles multiple selection, but I don't know if CKEditor does. If yes, then `CKEDITOR.dom.selection#selectRanges` is what you need. However, if you're only trying to extract contents of ranges then you don't have to select them first.

Comment: yes your solution works for me, i appreciate so much your help.